# Can I create Swift GUI interfaces by programming on ubuntu bash?

Tags: swift, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, subsystem

I'm so noob at swift and I founded how to install ubuntu subsystem at Windows 10 and I want to create Swift GUI interfaces working at the ubuntu bash on windows.

Can I? Are there any way to do that from VSCode on windows?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately isn't possible build UI with Swift on Windows or Linux because you need UIKit or SwiftUI to do it and these libraries are just available for Apple devices.